# Can I read input from GET inside a Controller Factory?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, zend-framework2, factory-pattern

This question is not explicitly about ZF2, but I often take ques from ZF2 for my code.  That said, most ZF2 examples I have seen process input inside a Controller Action.

Example:

```php
class YourController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function doStuffAction()
    {
        // ZF2's way to get input from $_GET variable
        $product =  $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('product');

        // Process    
        $processor = (new ProcessorFactory())->getProcessor($product);
        $output = $processor->processInput($data);
    }
}
```

Now, I would *like* to inject a `Processor` into my Controller.  Not create it inside the controller like I am doing above.  But since `Processor` depends on knowing the `$product`, which is only gotten from `$_GET`, I do not see any other way.

If I want to inject `Processor` into Controller, I have to move the line that populates `$product` variable outside of the Controller as well.

How can I do so without breaking OOP, ZF2, design patterns badly?  As in, I am under the impression that anything to do with `$_GET` is to be done inside a `Controller`, and not inside a `ControllerFactory`.  Unless perhaps I can break this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to apply the Dependency Inversion principle. Applying the D of [SOLI**D**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) acronym, only a few changes are needed.

```
class YourController
{

    /**
     * @var ProcessorFactory
     */
    protected $processorFactory;

    public function __construct(ProcessorFactory $processorFactory)
    {
        $this->processorFactory = $processorFactory;
    }

    public function doStuffAction()
    {
        $product =  $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('product');
        $processor = $this->processorFactory->getProcessor($product);
    }
}
```

You could improve by typehinting to an **I**nterface (SOL**I**D)

```
class YourController
{

    /**
     * @var ProcessorFactoryInterface
     */
    protected $processorFactory;

    public function __construct(ProcessorFactoryInterface $processorFactory)
    {
        $this->processorFactory = $processorFactory;
    }

    public function doStuffAction()
    {
        $product =  $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('product');
        $processor = $this->processorFactory->getProcessor($product);
    }
}
```

Now, if you want don't want your Controller to be responsible of initiating the creating process (**S**OLID), you can split it up some more.

```
class YourController
{

    /**
     * @var ProcessorInterface
     */
    protected $processor;

    public function __construct(ProcessorInterface $processor)
    {
        $this->processor = $processor;
    }

    public function doStuffAction()
    {
        $processor = $this->processor;
    }
}

class ControllerFactory
{
    /**
     * @var ProcessorFactory
     */
    protected $processorFactory;

    public function  __construct(ProcessorFactory $processorFactory)
    {
        $this->processorFactory = $processorFactory;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return new YourController($this->processorFactory->getProcessor());
    }
}

class ProcessorFactory
{
    /**
     * @var RouteMatch
     */
    protected $routeMatch;

    public function __construct(RouteMatch $routeMatch)
    {
        $this->routeMatch = $routeMatch;
    }

    public function getProcessor()
    {
        $processor = $this->createProcessor();
        // do stuff
        return $processor;
    }

    protected function createProcessor()
    {
        $product =  $this->routeMatch->getParam('product');

        // create processor

        return $processor;
    }
}
```

The following code would get you your controller.

```
$controllerFactory = new ControllerFactory(new ProcessorFactory(new RouteMatch()));
$yourController = $controllerFactory->create();
```

Now above code is more general code and not adapted for ZF2. A good move would then to involve the ZF2's servicemanager.

```
class YourController extends AbstractActionController
{

    /**
     * @var ProcessorInterface
     */
    protected $processor;

    public function __construct(ProcessorInterface $processor)
    {
        $this->processor = $processor;
    }

    public function doStuffAction()
    {
        $processor = $this->processor;
    }
}


class YourControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $controllers)
    {
        $services = $controllers->getServiceLocator();
        $processorFactory = $services->get('ProcessorFactory');
        return new YourController($processorFactory->getProcessor());
    }
}

class ProcessorFactory
{
    /**
     * @var RouteMatch
     */
    protected $routeMatch;

    public function __construct(RouteMatch $routeMatch)
    {
        $this->routeMatch = $routeMatch;
    }

    public function getProcessor()
    {
        $processor = $this->createProcessor();
        // do stuff
        return $processor;
    }

    protected function createProcessor()
    {
        $product =  $this->routeMatch->getParam('product');

        // create processor

        return $processor;
    }
}

class ProcessorFactoryFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $services)
    {
        return new ProcessorFactory($services->get('RouteMatch'));
    }
}
```

Above services/controllers and their factories should be registered with their ServiceManager/ControllerManager

```
$config = [
    'controllers' = [
        'factories' [
             'YourController' => 'YourControllerFactory',
        ],
    ],
    'service_manager' = [
        'factories' [
             'ProcessorFactory' => 'ProcessorFactoryFactory',
        ],
    ],
];
```

When a request gets dispatch to YourController, the ControllerManager returns a YourController instance with a Processor injected. Which Processor it gets depends on the request (a parameter inside RouteMatch).

Comment: It's a little convoluted, but the main idea I got is that you can call routematch and $_GET (RouteMatch) from inside a factory.

Comment: Well, $_GET and Routematch actually point to different things. Query variables ($_GET) are accessible using the Request object ($request->getQuery()), and Routematch contains the matched routename with some belonging variables.